# How to slice any Container to a buffered Image?

Tags: java, swing, pdf, jscrollpane, bufferedimage

Is there any implementation available in Java to get buffered images from a container

Eg: consider a `JScrollpane`, I will set the buffered Image size as 100*100, if the size of the scroll pane is 1000*100, I should get 10 buffered images, each buffered image of size 100*100 
(i.e) 1st buffered image from the position

1. (0, 0, 100,100)
2. (0, 100, 100,100)
3. (0, 200, 100,100)
4. (0, 300, 100,100)
5. ..
6. ..
7. ..
8. ..
9. ..
10. (0, 900, 100,100)

I will append all these buffered image in a PDF file.

Comment: Why slice the images? Why not create one large XObject for the complete image, insert this XObject once in the PDF and reuse it 10 times using a different clipping path. That's a much more elegant solution, resulting in a more optimal PDF, isn't it?

Comment: What is the problem?  Gaining an image of a component, or dividing the image into 10 parts?

Comment: need to save an jscrollpane into PDF (like screenshot), the size of the jscrollpane is too large, if i create a buffered image for the jscrollpane size, outofmemory error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this you mean? I unfortunately couldn't test it, but maybe if you can provide some demo code?

```
Container c = .. // your container..
Dimension d = c.getPreferredSize(); // your slices
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(d.width, d.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
c.paintComponents( be.createGraphics() );
```

Comment: the dimension of the container is (100000 * 1000), the statement new BufferedImage(100000 * 1000, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB) throws outofmemoryerror, so only i planned to slice the container into smaller buffered images

Comment: I need an api like                                                 BufferedImage[] convertComponenttoBufferedImage(Component c)                             {} which should process the component and convert into bufferedimages. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Screen Image](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) class to create an image of any component. You can also specify a Rectangle to get a sub image of the component.

> I need an api like BufferedImage[] convertComponenttoBufferedImage(Component c) {} which should process the component and convert into bufferedimages. is it possible?

Create a loop for the columns/rows of the image and change the dimensions of each Rectangle when you invoke the ScreenImage class.